# Php Inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I am using PHP 5.3 stable release and sometimes I encounter very inconsistent behaviours. As far as I know in inheritance all attributes and methods(private, public and protected) in super class are passed child class.

```
class Foo
{
    private $_name = "foo";
}
class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }
}
$o = new Bar();
echo $o->getName();

//Notice: Undefined property: Bar::$_name in ...\test.php on line 11
```

But when Foo::$_name attribute is defined "public" it doesn't give error. PHP has own OO rules???

Thanks

**Edit:** Now all things are clear.
Actually I was thinking in "inheritance" a new class is created and inherits all members independent from its ancestor. I didn't know "accessing" rules and inheritance rules are the same.

***Edit***
According to your comments this snippet should give an error. But it is working.

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar = "baz";

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{}

$o = new Bar;
echo $o->getBar();      //baz
```

Comment: [OOP5 Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: Key thing is that the private tag makes the member variable inaccessible to child instances of that class.

if you had declared it as 'protected $_name' it would have worked properly and not been public.

Comment: No. Those rules are exactly the same as in Java and C++ where PHP's object model was taken from.

Comment: Since getBar() is defined in the parent class, it can access the private member variable.

Comment: return $this->bar; Here $this refers to Bar object and Bar class has no $bar variable. How could it be?

Comment: Brad is correct.  Because `getBar()` is defined in `class Foo`, `$this` refers to the scope within `Foo`.

Answer (score 12):

From [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> The visibility of a property or method
>   can be defined by prefixing the
>   declaration with the keywords `public`,
>   `protected` or `private`. Class members
>   declared `public` can be accessed
>   everywhere. Members declared `protected`
>   can be accessed only within the class
>   itself and by inherited and parent
>   classes. Members declared as `private`
>   may only be accessed by the class that
>   defines the member.

```
class A
{
    public $prop1;     // accessible from everywhere
    protected $prop2;  // accessible in this and child class
    private $prop3;    // accessible only in this class
}
```

And No, this is not different from other languages implementing the same keywords.

**Regarding your second edit and code snippet:**

No, this should not give an error because `getBar()` is inherited from `Foo` and `Foo` has visibility to `$bar`. If `getBar()` was defined or overloaded in `Bar` it would not work. See http://codepad.org/rlSWx7SQ

Answer (score 3):

Your assumptions aren't correct. Protected and public members are 'passed on'. Private members aren't. To my knowledge this is typical for many OOP languages.

Answer (score 1):

**Private** methods and variables cannot be accessed by child classes or externally - only by the class itself.
Use **Protected** if you want the variable accessible by the child but inaccessible to outside classes.